# Nested indirect enums in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, avplayer, swift3

I am writing an [*AudioManager* in Swift 3](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftAudioManager) (please help me with a better name than *"AudioManager"*) that wraps `AVPlayer`. The aim is to have a player handling interrupts, route change and support custom playback rate, sleep timer, command center, now playing info etc. Since `AVFoundation` is heavily *event driven*, making use of `KVO` and `NSNotification` it makes sense to make my project event driven as well. I have incorporated a messaging system, where different parts of the app sends events up the chain, all the way up to the root node, *AudioManager*. So I wanted an event representation as `enum`, because that's what makes most sense. However, I want my events grouped by e.g. *RouteChange*, *BufferingEvent*, *InterruptionEvent* etc. So I finally got it working using *nested enums*.

I am writing an example GUI, which then can *tune in* to events from *AudioManager*, instead of having to use `NSNotification`, or *closures*.

**EDITTED** using the answer provided by @andyvn22

```
enum AudioError: Error {
    indirect case buffering(Buffering)
    enum Buffering {
        case unknown
    }

    indirect case playback(Playback)
    enum Playback {
        case failedToSetupAVAsset
        case failedToSetupAVItem
    }

    init(_ buffering: Buffering) {
        self = .buffering(buffering)
    }

    init(_ playback: Playback) {
        self = .playback(playback)
    }
}

enum Event {
    case failure(AudioError)

    init(_ error: AudioError) {
        self = .failure(error)
    }

    init(_ bufferingError: AudioError.Buffering) {
        self = .failure(AudioError.buffering(bufferingError))
    }

    init(_ playbackError: AudioError.Playback) {
        self = .failure(AudioError.playback(playbackError))
    }

    indirect case buffering(Buffering)
    enum Buffering {
        case idle, started, finished
    }

    indirect case playback(Playback)
    enum Playback {
        case tick, wasPaused
    }

    indirect case route(RouteChange)
    enum RouteChange {
        case unavailable, available
    }

    indirect case interruption(Interruption)
    enum Interruption {
        case interrupted, interruptionEnded
    }
}
```

You can paste this all in to a **Swift Playground**, and add the `handle` methods and calling it with the example calls below:

```
func handle(_ error: AudioError.Buffering) {
    handle(AudioError.buffering(error))
}

func handle(_ error: AudioError) {
    handle(Event.failure(error))
}

func handle(_ event: Event) {
    switch event {
    case .failure(let errorType):
        print("failure", terminator: " ")
        switch errorType {
        case .playback(let error):
            print("playback", terminator: " ")
            switch error {
            case .failedToSetupAVAsset:
                print("setupAVAsset")
            case .failedToSetupAVItem:
                print("setupAVItem")
            }
        case .buffering(let error):
            print("buffering", terminator: " ")
            switch error {
            case .unknown:
                print("unknown")
            }
        }
    case .buffering(let buffering):
        print("buffering", terminator: " ")
        switch buffering {
        case .idle:
            print("idle")
        case .started:
            print("started")
        case .finished:
            print("finished")
        }
    case .playback(let playback):
        print("playback", terminator: " ")
        switch playback {
        case .tick:
            print("tick")
        case .wasPaused:
            print("wasPaused")
        }
    default:
        print("unhandled case")
    }
}

/* All these are equivalent */
handle(Event.failure(.buffering(.unknown)))
handle(Event(.buffering(.unknown)))
handle(Event(AudioError(.unknown)))
handle(Event(.unknown))
handle(.unknown)
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
However, it is a bit tedious to write `handle(Event(.buffering(.unknown)))` which already is the short version of `handle(Event.failure(.buffering(.unknown)))`.

**My question:**
 
Is it possible to create an `Event` with `case .failure` using just an inner case inside either *AudioError.Buffering* or *AudioError.Playback* **?**

Which would allow be to do something like this:

```
handle(Event(.unknown))
```

Assuming *AudioError.Buffering* and *AudioError.Playback* does not share a case with the same name...

**Maybe I have missed some cool part of Swift 3 what would allow this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes--by overloading initializers, you can allow for initialization by any of the subtypes. For example:

```
enum AudioError: Error {
    indirect case buffering(Buffering)
    enum Buffering {
        case unknown
    }

    indirect case playback(Playback)
    enum Playback {
        case failedToSetupAVAsset
        case failedToSetupAVItem
    }

    init(_ buffering: Buffering) {
        self = .buffering(buffering)
    }

    init(_ playback: Playback) {
        self = .playback(playback)
    }
}

let example = AudioError(.failedToSetupAVAsset) //this works...
let other = AudioError(.unknown) //but so does this.
```

By creating many initializers likes these for each subtype, but on `Event` rather than `AudioError`, you can nest as much as you'd like without complicating syntax.

Comment: very nice, I had to add some more inits to get it to work, will updated my questions with the solution, thanks!

Comment: I added an two inits to Event, one for AudioError.Buffering and one for AudioError.Playback, and I added two inits in AudioError. I also created two convenience `func handle`, which enables very nice syntax.